# Whats wrong with this IF statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning about MySQL, I'm using PHPMyAdmin in wamp server. Now I'm trying to make a trigger for a table but I'm having troubles when I insert data in the parent table. I just want to evaluate a field named `Es_Ban` and depending on its value fill a table o another
here is my code:

```
IF new.es_ban = 1 THEN
INSERT INTO Banca(Ban_Due,Nom_Ban,Mon_Banca)
VALUES (new.Usu_Log, new.Ban_Age, 0 );
END IF;
```

After inserting a row in the parent named logins I get this error:

```
1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
fails (`prueba`.`banca`, CONSTRAINT `banca_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY 
(`Ban_Due`) REFERENCES `logins` (`Usu_Log`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The only way I got it to work was by delenting the relationship between Login and Banca...

Comment: The `IF` statement seems fine. Your `INSERT` seems to have issues. Seems like you might need to insert a record in `logins` table first before you insert to `banca`.

Comment: Is there a `Usu_Log=  prueba` in your `logins` table?  It's trying to insert value `prueba`, but the record doesn't exist in table `logins`.

Comment: Tanks a lot for your help clinomaniac, the problem was in my trigger. Because it was "Before" and no "After" insert... I'm triying to voteup you but I dont know how